# Do modifiers from Theologies only count for 1 single skill each?

Tags: part-time-gods

Do the modifiers from theology give points for only single skills (like vessel), or to ALL 3 skills of a single manifestation?

For example, Ascendants: Shaping +2, Ruin +1.

Does this affect all 3 skills each or only 1 skill each? Thus is it only :

- ruin - blast +1, or is it
- ruin-blast +1 AND ruin-geas +1 AND ruin warrior + 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of them.

It affects any use of that Manifestation. :-)

Comment: Can you back up that answer in any way?   "Some guy said yes" is unlikely to help the OP, as it's clearly one of the two possible answers.

Comment: Unless "some guy" is the writer of the game. Which of course he might want to cite as credit to his credibility -he could, of course be a vile impostor...

Comment: @Nigralbus Didn't recognize the face at first due to the small image here. That aside even if he was not who he is it is further pointed into the directoin on the charsheet (which only features the manifetations themselves not the 3 parts of each).